# What is a recommended maximum file size?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

APS failed to translate this 3D model properly. It lacked some parts
https://grabcad.com/library/the-concept-of-the-heat-removal-system-of-a-high-flux-research-reactor-1

I thought this happened because the file size is too large.
What is a recommended maximum file size?

Comment: Could you please provide more details? How exactly did you translate the model? What was the main SLDASM file that you used as the entry point for the translation? And which parts were missing?

Answer (score 0):

From the limited information I have I can only say that the model file size doesn't seem that bad. There's many *.SLDPRT and *.SLDASM files referencing each other so make sure that:

- you're translating a ZIP file containing *all* the *.SLDPRT and *.SLDASM files
- you're specifying the proper *master* *.SLDASM file as the `rootFilename` parameter in the [POST job](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/jobs/job-POST/) endpoint